# How to test commonsMultipartFile files?

Tags: spring, unit-testing, grails, groovy, spock

everybody,
I am testing using spock in Grails for certain methods that need a CommonMultipartFile as input parameters.

My problem is how to create these files so that no local ones are generated. Some of them must use a request.getFile and so I thought I would use the MockMultipartFile class in all these methods.

The problem is that it tells me that you can't cast from MockMultipartFile to CommonsMultipartFile at the following casting:

```
CommonsMultipartFile commonsMultipartFile = (CommonsMultipartFile) request.getFile("filecsv")
```

Does anyone know how to do such a casting?

P.S.: Prior to this I have only done the following:

```
MultipartFile multipartFile = new MockMultipartFile("filecsv","filecsv", "")
request.addFile(multipartFile)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not mention that you are using types from Spring, I had to do a web search first. Don't keep people trying to help you guessing. Instead, please explain or at least tag the question accordingly (I just did that for you).

You cannot cast incompatible types. Both [`CommonsMultipartFile`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/commons/CommonsMultipartFile.html) and [`MockMultipartFile`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mock/web/MockMultipartFile.html) directly extend `Object` and implement the `MultipartFile` and `InputStreamSource` interfaces. So you can only cast to something they have in common, i.e. one of those interfaces.

BTW, I have never used Grails, but its API seems to have a [`GrailsMockMultipartFile`](http://docs.grails.org/3.1.2/api/org/grails/plugins/testing/GrailsMockMultipartFile.html) which extends the Spring `MockMultipartFile` and provides an implementation of `transferTo` that doesn't use the file system.